# Dependency problems in apt/dpkg

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dependencies

When I try to start Synaptic I get asked to run `dpkg --configure -a` manually, so when I did that I got this dpkg: dependency error:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.112.118); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 4.4.0.109.114.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-generic
```

So what can I do now?

Comment: What led Synaptic to ask you to do that? Do you *understand* what the dependency error means?

Comment: please post the output of synaptic before you tried to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: SOLVED: Was just to run synaptic again and fix broken package. /Cheers

Comment: user535733. Yes I understand what dependency problem means. Linux header was older than was required. Why? I do not know..probably, some interruption under upgrade?